# TypeError: expected bytes, str found [while running 'Writing to DB/ParDo(_WriteToRelationalDBFn) while writing to db from using beam-nuggets

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, beam-sql

@mohaseeb

I am trying below example to write data from pub\sub to postgresql.Getting below error while writing pub\sub data into postgresql. "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 545, in _colnames_from_description colname = description_decoder(colname) TypeError: expected bytes, str found [while running 'Writing to DB/ParDo(_WriteToRelationalDBFn)-ptransform-74904']

could you please help to fix it.

````
    months = p | "Reading month records" >> beam.Create([
        {'name': 'Jan', 'num': 1},
        {'name': 'Feb', 'num': 2},
    ])
    months | 'Writing to Sqlite table' >> relational_db.Write(
        source_config=relational_db.SourceConfiguration(
            drivername='sqlite',
            database='/tmp/months_db.sqlite',
            create_if_missing=True
        ),
        table_config=relational_db.TableConfiguration(
            name='months',
            create_if_missing=True```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to the version of pg8000. Try `pip install pg8000==1.16.5`. It looks like a breaking change was introduced in 1.16.6. More details can be found here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5645

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what `_WriteToRelationalDBFn` is doing from the code snippet you posted but I would image that you need to transform your record column name from str type to bytes, for example: `column_name = column_name.encode()`

Comment: thanks, I have tried with encoded column names, I am facing still same issue.

Comment: I am facing same issue for postgresql as well  while writing records to google cloud postgresql .